# Regular Expression for matching number greater than specified decimal number

Tags: regex, string-matching

I want to a match version numbers greater than 4.1.
I constructed the following Regex for this

```
(([4-9]+\d*(\.((\*)|([2-9]+(\.((\*)|([0-9]+)))?)))?))
```

But it matches even '4' and does not match '5.1', '6.1' etc.

How to construct such a regular expression? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
([4-9]\.[2-9]\d*|[4-9]\.\d\d+|[5-9](\.\d+)?|\d\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

matches all versions above 4.1

Edit: fixed it for Versions without a dot

Comment: That expression will have problems if used in C#, because in C# the `\d` is even non-european digits, like ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹... (something quite ugly!)

Comment: @xanatos: i didnt know that, sounds like microsoft logic :D. well, no language specific was given, i guess he can switch the `\d` to `[0-9]` if he has that problem

Comment: @xanatos - Learn something new everyday. Sometimes I want to take back what I learned though :-(

Comment: In Python if you activate the `re.UNICODE` it does the same thing http://ideone.com/eQE2d2

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
(4\.(1[0-9]*[1-9]|[2-9][0-9]*)|([5-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)
```

This will match:

- `4.` followed by either:

  - `1` followed by zero or more `0-9` and one or more `1-9`
  - `2-9` followed by zero or more `0-9`

  ***or***
- Either `5-9` or `1-9` followed by one or more `0-9`
- followed by an optional decimal point and zero or more `0-9`

Depending on how this will be used, you might want to consider adding start / end anchors around your pattern so that no other characters will be allowed:

```
^(4\.(1[0-9]*[1-9]|[2-9][0-9]*)|([5-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)$
```

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%284%5C.%281%5B0-9%5D%2a%5B1-9%5D%7C%5B2-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%2a%29%7C%28%5B5-9%5D%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%28%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%29%24&input=4%0A4.1%0A4.101%0A5.1%0A6.1).

Comment: you need to escape the first dot. also the questions asks for versions `greater than 4.1`. yours matches 4.1